# Passing parameters to async function Aurelia

Tags: typescript, async-await, aurelia

I'm have async function which takes arguments.
When I'm call it in click.tirgger="myFunc(param1, param2)" or pass it to child component as callback parameter not exist.
When I'm removing async keyword everything start working.

```
 <button type="button" click.trigger="getPlayersData(currentPage)" class="btn btn-info col-lg-1">Show</button>

async getPlayersData(currentPage: number){
  var data = await this.reportService.getPlayersData(start, end,  currentPage, this.rowCount); 
  //do something 
}

async getPlayersData(startDate, endDate, page, rowCount): Promise<ReportModel> {
    try {          
        var response = await this.http.fetch('api/reportController/getPlayerBusinessReport?startDate=' + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&page=' + page + '&rowCount=' + rowCount, {
            method: 'get'
        });
        var data = await response.json();

       // form ReportModel object
       //report = ReportModel(data)

        return Promise.resolve(report);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        //error handling
    }

}
```

How could I'm solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and JS Code.

Comment: Added code to post

Comment: When you remove "async" where? And what does not exist? response?

Comment: When i'm remove async in getPlayersData(currentPage: number) all ok. parameter currentPage does not exist, it undefined when i call method with async keyword

Comment: I suppose, `click.trigger="getPlayersData(currentPage)"` is expression that is parsed by aurelia templating engine and not processed by babel, so you just cannot call async functions in that way